# How to debug a tensorflow application in windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently I am working in a Tensorflow application "in eclipse pydev", and I have a big problem. I can't debug correctly my application, for example when I try to know if my application loaded my images with:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
            tf.train.match_filenames_once(images_dataset_folder), shuffle = True)
```

I don't figure out how to know if this line work correctly, please if anyone know something about that, please advise me

Thanks,

Comment: Two suggestions, 1st read the error message and try to give a name to your tensors, so you the names in the error msg. 2nd may you need to download the binaries so can debug in a lower level !

Comment: What do you mean by "download the binaries" ?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources